# Connection to AWS database only works in Development

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-amplify

### Problem

I created an app and deployed it via *AWS Amplify*. The app works, but every time I try to do an operation which uses my database I get an error. The peculiar thing is that when I am developing on localhost and connecting to the database, everything works.

### Debugging

I checked whether the environment variables are set correctly and they are. When checking the cloud logs, I can see this error: `code: 'ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'`.

Could this be a problem with the security group or  something else? There are no problems connecting from my local ip. There is only one inbound rule specified:

[image: Inbound rules]

I am not really well versed in all the *IAM* management stuff, so there is a good chance that I have messed this up. Any hints or help are very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Timeout suggests a network connectivity issue between your application and the database. See [How do I resolve problems when connecting to my Amazon RDS DB instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/)

Comment: Yeah,  I found that article, but unfortunately, half of it sounds like ghibberish to me and I  am pretty lost even with it.

Comment: Is this an RDS database instance or Aurora? Aurora is a little stricter about the networking side (the databases are inside a VPC). In addition to having the right inbound rule in your security group, you'll need to set the 'publicly accessible' flag for the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

If you `amplify mock function ....` test a Lambda, I believe it runs using the permissions of the amplify-cli user and not necessarily the Lambda's actual permissions.

Try `amplify env checkout prod` so your local environment is pointing to the 'production' environment on AWS. Test the front-end (carefully, knowing you're making changes in production) and see if that works.

You'll probably need to log out of the front-end website and log back in using a production user.

If that fails, then I suspect something is different between your dev & prod environments. Look at your environment variables. Make sure you didn't hard-code any table names -dev instead of -${process.env.ENV} etc.

IF the above test does work, then consider the differences between production and development environments. If everything is managed by Amplify, then the should be the same. If you have some pre-existing resources, then you'll need to examine the permissions resources have to talk to those resources. Did you grab an ARN from somewhere in your dev and not from prod? etc.

Comment: Would permissions errors ever cause connection timeouts?

Comment: I don't have the amplify cli installed. I simply connected the repo with aws and so the app is redeployed on every push to a specific branch. There are no hardcoded table names. Or can I run the `amplify` command somewhere in aws?

Comment: You use amplify cli on your local machine to add/remove/update resources, push backend changes, etc. I've never used Amplify exclusively for hosting. Sounds like @jarmod link is your best bet for next steps.